# Django | PostgreSQL | ManyToManyField vs ForeignKey performance

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am going to a Vehicle table, which has two damage types - **primary** and **secondary** (optional). Not more, only these two. And I am wondering because I expect, that the **Vehicle** table will have really a lot of records in near future, about **1M+** and I am not sure if I should use **ManyToMany** field or two **ForeignKeys** with disabled **related_name**

```
class Damage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
```

Should I use this solution:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    damage_primary = models.ForeignKey(Damage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    damage_secondary = models.ForeignKey(Damage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, related_name='+')
```

OR this one:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    damage = models.ManyToManyField(Damage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What is the best practice, please? Because internal table, which Django will create when I will use ManyToManyField will have really a lot of records, if, in Vehicles table, there will be 1 000 000 and more records, in future.

Thank you very much for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only two damage type, you want two foreign key.

The *related_name* does not have any database performance influence.